# FFmpeg (HLS) - Split segments by size rather than time (or limit segment size)

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, fluent-ffmpeg

So I have a ffmpeg command with the following parameters (in NodeJS, but it doesn't matter):

```
'-start_number 0',
'-hls_key_info_file ' + HLSKEY_PATH,
'-hls_time 5',
'-hls_playlist_type vod',
'-hls_segment_filename seg-%d.ts'
```

Everything's working fine, but there's a problem with the size of each segment.
Why can't ffmpeg create segments by size rather than time? In this case `-hls_time 5`. I was hoping doing something like `-hls_size 4096` but there's no option for that, at least from what I know. Or can I at least set a limit? Like: "Don't create segments bigger than 4MB, split them again if necessary."

I know I could encode the file again and then there wouldn't be segments which vary in size that much, but this is no option and alternative for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually, ffmpeg can. But results may not be what you expect. It's -hls_segment_size *bytes*. Set hls_time low.

Answer (score 0):

Not ALL frames have the same amount of information in them. Video compression works in a way that some frames have LESS information and others have MORE. Technically, then, if the segment duration in milliseconds is ALWAYS the same, there is no way the fragment sizes will be the same.

I think there is no option for what you're asking.

There is a "**-fs**" (output file size) command, but I think it works to limit the size of the whole output, and not just segments.

In your place, if the segment sizes are bothering me, I would just lower the duration by one second, then two, and see. Good luck.